# Excel function to sort two columns into one

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two txt files. First one has data like so.

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

the second one has data like so.

```
A1
A2
+++
B1
B2
B3
+++
C1
C2
C3
C4
+++

+++
E1
E2
E3
E4
E5
E6
```

I want them sorted like so.

```
A,A1
A,A2
B,B1
B,B2
B,B3
...
...
...
D,
E,E1
E,E2
E,E3
E,E4
E,E5
E,E6
```

Notice that column D from first txt file has no matching sub columns! How can I sort these data?

Comment: Since Excel doesn't "sort text files", this doesn't seem like an Excel question. If you import the two text files, you have two different tables. Your question is how to combine the tables, and then sort them, producing the key in question, but removing the special case of a key "X, " where there is also "X, YY"?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an Excel question, but having to massage data files was something I often had to do in the past, and Excel can be put to use on these one-off data transformation problems.

Load the first into a sheet and add a column called "Type" and populate it with "Primary", like so:

[image: First File Spreadsheet with Type column]

Import the second file into a sheet, and add a column called "Type", and use a formula to populate the type column. I'm assuming from your example you have some "junk" delimiters, and this formula can flag those.

[image: Second File Spreadsheet with Type column]

The formula for the example data would look like below. You can change the literal or logic according to the actual data.

```
=IF(A7="+++","Ignored","Secondary")
```

Merge the two tables (cut and paste is fine) into a new sheet, and sort them by key, so you end up with this sheet:

[image: Spreadsheet with merged tables, after sorting]

Now we can get the composite key by adding two columns with formulas. Add a "Derived Primary" column with this formula.

```
=IF(ROW(B2)>2,IF(B2="Primary","A2,C1),"")
```

(The formula above assumes you have a header row like my example and the data starts on the second row.)

Adding a "Composite Key" column that uses this formula:

```
=IF(B2="Ignored","",IF(B2="Primary",IF(C2=C3,"", C2 &","),C2 &","&A2))
```

Basically, the logic above checks for one of three conditions:

1. "Ignored" type: show nothing in the composite key.
2. "Secondary" type: combine the "Derived Primary" with the "Key"
3. "Primary" type: if the derived primary value of the next row matches the current derived primary value, show nothing, otherwise, show the derived primary value. (i.e. a singleton primary key with no secondaries.)

Then your sheet will look like this:

[image: Final spreadsheet with composite key]

You can copy the last column out, and sort it to remove the blanks.

I'm guessing your real situation has a lot more data and the values may vary for the junk delimiters, so adjust the formulas as necessary. Hope it helps.